# Как понять, что метод в классе относится к интерфейсу?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть у меня интерфейс

```
interface A
{
    void foo();
}
```

Есть класс

```
class B: A 
{
    public void foo()
    {
    }
}
```

все хорошо, но есть два вопроса

1. Как смотря на класс В можно понять, что метод `foo()` это метод интерфеса? Нет никакого слова типо `override` или `virtual` и становиться не понятно или это метод класса или интерфеса
2. Это приводит к тому, что если я удаляю имплементацию интерфейса из класса, то ничего не происходит

```
class B 
{
    public void foo()
    {
    }
}
```

нет никакого предупреждения о том, что этот метод относился к интерфейсу или что то подобное

Но я уверен, что я просто, что то не знаю , как с этим работать в C#

**P.S.**
скажем это отлично имлементировано в `Java`, `Kotlin`, `C++` и т.д., `C#` достаточно продвинутый язык и странно, что этого нет тут

**Правка**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине видно, что есть класс `IndexableTask` который имплементирует интерфейс `IIndexable` и переопределяет его два метода `GetIdx()` и `SetIdx(int idx)` и если смотреть на класс то не понятно, толи это методы класса, толи это переопределенные методы интерфейса

Comment: Подсветка синтаксиса к языку отношения не имеет, [это фишка IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADPag.png)

Comment: Подозреваю, что возможно такой функционал есть в CodeLens или решарпере. Попробуй покопать в єту сторону

Comment: @tym32167 ну хорошо подсветка фишка идеа, но что насчет того, что разработчик использует интерфейс и в итоге по понятно какие методы относятся к классу, а какие к интерфейсу?

Comment: на скрине выше вы можете увидеть пометку слева на полях у метода Foo класса - эта пометка говорит о том, что этот метод связан с другим классом или интерфейсом. То есть все методы с подобными пометками вас и интересуют. Если навести курсор на пометку, вам напишут, с чем именно метод связан.

Comment: Вы можете явно указать, что метод реализует интерфейс, используя такую запись в классе B: `void A.foo()`.

Comment: @tym32167 я не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду `на скрине выше`. В любом случае я только, что добавил свой скрин в вопрос и там видно, что нет никаких пометок

Comment: @zed что? Ниче не понял... куда, что указать?

Comment: Да, точно помню, что в решарпере такая фича была с подсветкой на полях спец. иконок.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Обновление от 05.06.2021*

В Visual Studio 2019 v16.10 такая функциональность, наконец, [появилась](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-v16-10-and-v16-11-preview-1-are-available-today/#visualize-and-navigate-inheritance-chains) штатно

По умолчанию она отключена, но вы можете ее включить в настройках: <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Text Editor</kbd> > <kbd>C#</kbd> > <kbd>Advanced</kbd> и установить чекбокс <kbd>Show inheritance margin</kbd>

[image: скриншот окна настроек]

Выглядит это так:

[image: Пример работы]

---

На момент ответа такой фичи в языке нет.

Остается только воспользоваться средствами среды разработки. В настройках Visual Studio 2019 (16.4.1) я ничего такого не нашел, поэтому придется установить какое-нибудь расширение для этого.

Например, вот это, первое которое я нашел и бесплатное для использования: [Inheritance Margin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamHarwell.InheritanceMargin)

[image: пример работы расширения]

Проблему оставшихся методов после удаления декларации из интерфейса это, конечно, не решает (как это решается в упомянутых вами языках?). Метод в классе останется. Но, с другой стороны, каждый публичный метод класса, который не объявлен в каком-либо интерфейсе должен вызывать подозрения и обращать на себя дополнительное внимание. Да и количество ссылок, которые отображает CodeLens должно убавиться, но не до нуля, конечно, останутся ссылки на тесты, которые этот конкретный класс тестируют.

Comment: А как установить это расширение? Я перешел по ссылке, там предлагается скачать файл, но как его установить в VS?

Comment: @Aleksey, можно скачать и запустить. А можно прямо из студии в окне extensions вбить название и установить оттуда

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете сделать явную имплементацию метода вот так:

```
class B: A 
{
    void A.foo()
    {
    }
}
```

Такой подход особенно полезен, если класс реализует несколько интерфейсов сразу.

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-interface

Comment: А как потом использовать этот метод внутри класса скажем? Если я хочу к нему обратиться?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Есть несколько способов: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868861