# Как отметить, что метод имплементирует интерфейс?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В общем проблема такая, я использую VS2017 обычную версию и вот у меня есть интерфейс `A` и в нем (для примера) есть один метод `foo()`, в другом классе `B` я имплементирую его. Результат, в классе `B` я вижу, что есть метод `foo()`, но нет никакой отметки о том, что этот метод является имплементацией интерфейса.

Я как то находил такой плагин, который подсфечивал сбоку от таких методов зелетой точкой и тогда хоть как то можно было понять, какие методы являются имплементацией, а какие методы самого класса. Но имя этого плагина было утеряно и теперь поковырявшись в гугле вижу, что все советуют только платные плагины такие так `ReSharper` или что то подобное.

Есть бесплатные альтернативы его

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9ca6ce79-f518-4cca-98ca-6d60a6f7cb36/free-resharper-alternatives-?forum=visualstudiogeneral

но судя по описанию я не уверен, что там есть подсветка интерфесов. В общем мне очень нравился тот утеряный плагин который зеленой точкой подсвечивал такие методы, если кто то использует буду рад узнать, или если кто использует другие бесплатные альтернативы для такой цели тоже спасибо!

**UPD**

язык С# (но круто если и c++ тоже будет подсвечивать)

Comment: Вы хотя бы уточнили язык, но похоже, тут C#

Comment: Я так понимаю, здесь то же самое спрашивают? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1283007/184217

Comment: ТС, у вас, по-видимому проблемы с памятью :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1057636/218063 или что здесь происходит?

Comment: @АндрейNOP О, вот он же:) спасибо большое! В целом когда я написал в вопросе `Но имя этого плагина было утеряно` я имел ввиду, что не смог найти этот пост, хотя перерыл историю вопросов дважды... в любом случае спасибо, можете закинуть в ответ я вам присвою приз так сказать:)

Comment: Нет, надо написать модераторам чтобы отменили конкурс и закрыть вопрос как дубликат. Если же хотите наградить тот ответ, можно завести конкурс там

Comment: Как найти — перейти в свой профиль, нажать на метку [visual-studio] среди своих меток, откроется список ваших вопросов/ответов с этой меткой, найти нужный (их там сейчас всего 5)

Comment: @АндрейNOP поиск по меткам, никогда бы не подумал, что это может быть так удобно, во всяком случае удобнее, чем перелистсывать все вопросы:) супер, пасибо

Comment: @АндрейNOP во всяком случае в поддержку написал, так что жду ответ от них

Comment: @АндрейNOP В итоге поддержка отменила конкурс, но насчет того как присвоить вам балы на ранее отвеченый вопрос так и не ответили (так как там уже есть 50 баллов и я не могу присвоить еще 50, только 100) так что встретимся в будующих вопросах :)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, не заморачивайтеся, баллы меня уже давно не интересуют :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP понял:)