# Иконка отображения членов интерфейса

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В Resharper сбоку над членами класса, которые реализуют тот или иной интерфейс отображается значок.

Можно ли подобное сделать без Reshaper или каким-нибудь бесплатным плагином?

Comment: Наверно стоит предоставить скриншот, может название этой функции для тех, кто не использует Resharper? Ведь сейчас ваш вопрос для многих звучит как "мне нужен значок сбоку (над?) членом класса" и вот как такое понимать людям?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1057756/184217